# Get Desktop Notifications On Linux Programmatically

Tags: c, linux, freedesktop.org, libnotify, notify-send

I want to develop a notification daemon with an applet. When an app sends a notification to a user for example Discord. I want to get the notification and show it to the user and store the notifications in the applet. I know how to send notifications but I don't know how to get the notifications programmatically. I research freedesktop.Notifications but I can't figure it out.